# Cosmos DB ConnectionPolicy

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

Cosmos DB supports a ConnectionPolicy that can provide multi-homing and automatic retries.  In looking through the docs and Gremlin.NET code I don't see any options to set a connection policy on the GremlinServer or GremlinClient.

Can multi-homing and retry policies be utilized with the Cosmos Graph API?

If not, has anyone created a solution that implements multi-homing?  I've already implemented an automatic retry implementation and was looking at implementing an automatic failover implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such configuration option in Gremlin Server. I believe that the `ConnectionPolicy` is only significant to CosmosDB and its non-TinkerPop oriented connection methods. In other words, TinkerPop's [Gremlin.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Gremlin.Net/) won't work with that.

There has been some thinking that TinkerPop could do more to make it possible for graph providers (like CosmosDB, DSE Graph, etc) who have their own connection transports to make them available through TinkerPop standard clients. TinkerPop does that already for bytecode based requests, but not script based ones, so the idea would be to make that available for the latter.